# PHP PDO Unix socket to Postgresql fails

Tags: php, postgresql, apache, selinux

Testing out a LAMP like application, fails with:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

After a lot of troubleshooting, I am stumped. I may have to resort to reinstalling linux to fix any issues I introduced by blindly hacking away. Before I do that, is there any way to debug this to get at the root cause?

***This is my LAMP box:***

- Postgresql 14
- Fedora Linux 36 (Workstation Edition)
- php 4.1.12
- Apache 2.2

***This is what I have tried so far:***

1. Check that the file exists. It does, but is the lock a problem?

```
[xxx@mybox~]$ sudo ls -al /tmp/.s.*
srwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres  0 Nov 28 12:10 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 48 Nov 28 12:10 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock
```

2. Try to connect with php. It connects and returns expected table data from Postgresql.

`php /var/www/html/lamp/connect.php`

3. Try with curl. Errors.

`curl http://localhost/lamp/connect.php`

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
> Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

*Test file connect.php. Use PDO to connect to Postgresql:*

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

function connect(string $host, string $db, string $user, string $password): PDO
{
        try {
                $dsn = "pgsql:host=/tmp;port=5432;dbname=$db";

                // make a database connection
                return new PDO(
                        $dsn,
                        $user,
                        $password,
                        [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
                );
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
        }
}

return connect($host, $db, $user, $password);
```

4. I have tried troubleshooting SELinux following
   [Troubleshooting SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting).

I did find an audit log notice which relates directly to the issue, used *sealert* to allow the access required. That didn't work. I disabled the repair modules  may have screwed up SE because I can't find the denial anymore. Turning SE and Firewall off does not work either.

```
[peter@fedora ~]$ getenforce
Permissive
```

```
$ firewall-cmd --state
not running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern Ubuntu/Debian+systemd installs have a relegated /tmp/ directory for the Apache server process. It is from a feature of systemd called PrivateTmp. It's supposed to be more "secure" or something. This means /tmp/ from the command line doesn't equal /tmp/ from within PHP, instead being somewhere in `/var/tmp/`, e.g. `/var/tmp/blabla-0123456abcd`.

You can disable it by editing the `.service` file and setting `PrivateTmp=no`.

### Other workarounds

Try specifying `host=localhost:port=5432` in your `$dsn`. This'll force it connect over the "network."

```php
$dsn = "pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=$db";
```

If that doesn't work, try leaving out the `host=` and `port=` from your DSN. AFAIK this'll make PDO connect to the local socket:

```php
$dsn = "pgsql:dbname=$db";
```

Another workaround would be to have Postgres store its socket somewhere other than /tmp. See the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-UNIX-SOCKET-DIRECTORIES) on how to change this.

Comment: Excellent thank you! Specifying localhost and port works. I prefer the leaving host and port out, it seems cleaner. Tried it. You are right it does look for a socket, but in another location.../var/run. I did not try setting  PrivateTmp.